# textbox validated method does not work while assigning value to textbox

Tags: winforms, validation, textbox, c#-2.0

I am using c#.net 2.0 winforms. I use errorprovider control in my form to validate a textbox. While I programatically assign value to that textbox. textbox validated method does not take the value from the textbox or considers it a blank value.  How can I validate my textbox by without entering value in the textbox. Here is the code

```
private void textBox6_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bTest6 = txtRegExPinIsValid(textBox6.Text);
    if (bTest6)
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox6, "");
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox6, "This field must contain Exactly 6 digits");
    }
 }

 private bool txtRegExPinIsValid(string textToValidate)
 {
     Regex TheRegExpression;
     string TheTextToValidate;
     string TheRegExTest = @"^\d{6}$";
     TheTextToValidate = textToValidate;
     TheRegExpression = new Regex(TheRegExTest);
     // test text with expression 
     if (TheRegExpression.IsMatch(TheTextToValidate))
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
  }
```

While performing update operation I fill the textbox with values from the ms access table. If the value is correct, just leave it otherwise I have to update it. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: If i manually keep the cursor in each and every textbox and perform update operation everything works fine..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing the validation code in a separate method. Call that method from both the `Validated` event and the location in your code where you need to programatically validate, as shown below:

```
// Call this from wherever you need to validate a TextBox
void PerformValidation(TextBox textBox)
{
    bTest6 = txtRegExPinIsValid(textBox6.Text);
    if (bTest6)
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox6, "");
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox6, "This field must contain Exactly 6 digits");
    }
}

private void textBox6_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PerformValidation(textBox6);
}
```

Comment: Thank you brett!! You gave a perfect solution. I found an alternate solution. Assign all the bool values to "true". I force the validation method to consider the textbox as validated, Since the values are programatically assigned to textbox through query from table. While update operation,if i want to correct values in the textbox, validation method is called. otherwise i just leave it because bool value is already set to true.